# Passing a vector of integers to two separate functions but altered data gets passed to the other functions

Tags: java

*Update: Resolved did a deep copy, thanks for the help

I am using a vector of integers to simulate some sorting algorithms, when i insert numbers to the test vector and shuffle the order and pass it to a sorting function, if i pass the void sorting functions the same vector, when the vector gets sorted in a function previously passed the newly sorted vector gets passed to the function following it because it is already sorted i cannot show the sorting process. For example in my following code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Removes error given at when adding elems to int_vec
    public static void CreateVec (int array_len)
    {
      Vector <Integer> int_vec = new Vector(array_len);
      int temp_int = 1;
      int low_bound = 0;
      int high_bound = array_len - 1;

          for(int i = 0; i<array_len; i++)
          {
              int_vec.addElement(temp_int);// creating a vec in respect to array len
              temp_int ++;
          }

             Collections.shuffle(int_vec);
             System.out.println("OG vec: " + int_vec); //original vector (random order)
             BubbleSort(int_vec,array_len); //sending int_vec to bubble sort
             InsertionSort(int_vec,array_len); // retrieves newly sorted vector sorted from BubbleSort (problem)

    }
```

So my question follows, how can i keep sending my test vector (int_vec) with the randomly ordered elements rather than it keep sending the sorted vector to the other algorithms. Note i correctly implemented these algorithms, it works if i comment out the function calls to the other algorithm functions.

Answer (score 2):

Create a copy of `int_vec` with `new Vector<Integer>(int_vec)` and pass in the copy to your sorting methods.  This way, only the copy will get sorted, and `int_vec` will still be randomly ordered, and ready to be copied again for the next sorting method.

And yes, this is a shallow copy, but a deep copy is not needed here.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working ill post what my output is on a question response

Comment: Ended up doing a deep copy, it wasn't liking any shallow copies that i did

Answer (score 0):

it doesnt seem to be working i did the following

```
Vector <Integer> int_vec = new Vector(array_len);    
Vector <Integer> copy_bub = new Vector <Integer> (int_vec);
//...//
BubbleSort(int_vec,array_len);
InsertionSort(copy_bub,array_len);
```

and this is the output

```
Output:   
    OG vec: [4, 8, 9, 6, 10, 2, 1, 5, 3, 7]
    Copy vec: [4, 8, 9, 6, 10, 2, 1, 5, 3, 7]
    Bubble Vec: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    Insertion Vec: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    Insertion Vec: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    Insertion Vec: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    Insertion Vec: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    Insertion Vec: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    Insertion Vec: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    Insertion Vec: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    Insertion Vec: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    Insertion Vec: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    Insertion Vec: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```